# Remapping hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap Ctrl + Y to Ctrl + Shift + Z

Could I get any assistance?

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: That's the problem. I have no idea of where to begin. I'm seeking someone with Autohotkey knowledge that can solve this easily.

Comment: And? did the proposed solution work?

Answer (score 5):

Although this is indeed a poorly written question with little research to support any effort, here is your answer:

Assuming that you want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> in order to get a signal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

```
#Persistent
^y::^+z
```